# My application is stuck loading when I press "Login" or "Register"

Tags: python, html, sqlite

I am creating a log in and register page to access a game. However, the app wont load when I fill out the username and password and press the "Login" button. I have no idea why. The logs don't show anything either.

Code:

```
import wsgiref.simple_server
import urllib.parse
import sqlite3
import http.cookies
import random


def app(environ, start_response):
    path = environ['PATH_INFO']

    if path == '/login':
        if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET':
            return show_login_form(environ, start_response)
        elif environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
            return login(environ, start_response)

    elif path == '/register':
        if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET':
            return show_register_form(environ, start_response)
        elif environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
            return register(environ, start_response)

    elif path == '/logout':
        return logout(environ, start_response)

    elif path == '/account':
        return play_game(environ, start_response)

    else:
        start_response('404 Not Found', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
        return ['Page not found'.encode()]


def show_login_form(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html')]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return ["""
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Login Form</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="/login">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br><br>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
        <p>Don't have an account? <a href="/register">Register</a></p>
    </body>
    </html>
    """.encode()]


def login(environ, start_response):
    if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
        post_data = environ['wsgi.input'].read()
        post_data = urllib.parse.parse_qs(post_data)
        username = post_data[b'username'][0].decode()
        password = post_data[b'password'][0].decode()

        conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        try:
            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?', (username, password))
            result = cursor.fetchone()

            if result:
                status = '200 OK'
                response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html')]
                start_response(status, response_headers)
                return ["""
                <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Login Successful</title>
                    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=/account">
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h2>Login Successful</h2>
                    <p>Successfully logged in as {}!</p>
                    <p>Redirecting to game...</p>
                </body>
                </html>
                """.format(username).encode()]
            else:
                status = '200 OK'
                response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html')]
                start_response(status, response_headers)
                return ["""
                <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Login Failed</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h2>Login Failed</h2>
                    <p>Invalid username or password. Please try again.</p>
                </body>
                </html>
                """.encode()]

        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            status = '500 Internal Server Error'
            response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html')]
            start_response(status, response_headers)
            return ["""
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Server Error</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>Server Error</h2>
                <p>An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later.</p>
                <p>Error details: {}</p>
            </body>
            </html>
            """.format(e).encode()]

    else:
        start_response('405 Method Not Allowed', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
        return ['Method not allowed'.encode()]


def show_register_form(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html')]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return ["""
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Register</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Register Form</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="/register">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br><br>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
        <p>Already have an account? <a href="/login">Login</a></p>
    </body>
    </html>
    """.encode()]


def register(environ, start_response):
    if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
        post_data = environ['wsgi.input'].read()
        post_data = urllib.parse.parse_qs(post_data)
        username = post_data[b'username'][0].decode()
        password = post_data[b'password'][0].decode()

        conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        try:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)', (username, password))
            conn.commit()

            status = '200 OK'
            response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html')]
            start_response(status, response_headers)
            return ["""
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Registration Successful</title>
                <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=/login">
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>Registration Successful</h2>
                <p>Account created successfully!</p>
                <p>Redirecting to login page...</p>
            </body>
            </html>
            """.encode()]

        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            status = '500 Internal Server Error'
            response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html')]
            start_response(status, response_headers)
            return ["""
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Server Error</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>Server Error</h2>
                <p>An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later.</p>
                <p>Error details: {}</p>
            </body>
            </html>
            """.format(e).encode()]

    else:
        start_response('405 Method Not Allowed', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
        return ['Method not allowed'.encode()]




if __name__ == '__main__':
    httpd = wsgiref.simple_server.make_server('', 8000, app)
    print("Serving on http://localhost:8000/login")
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2023 10:54:07] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 559
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2023 11:01:39] "GET /register HTTP/1.1" 200 567
```

[image: I cannot get farther than this point in my app]

The image above is the farthest I can get with my app before its stuck loading. I would also like to note that the username and password are being added to my database when I press "Register". So the communication between my sql database is successful.

Comment: Logs both show GETs, where are the logs for when you POST to these endpoints as that is where the actual login seems to happen? It may be useful to add some custom logging into the login endpoint using `print()` to help you verify the correct logic is being executed, and where it is making it to in your methods.